# Prove that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G/M×G/N$ - Abstract Alg

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Let $M$ and $N$ be normal subgroups of a group $G$ such that $M∩N$=$⟨e⟩$.
Prove that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G/M×G/N$.

I'm struggling on how to do this problem. I have seen similiar problems in which $G = MN$ and they prove that $G/(M ∩ N)$ is isomorphic to $(G/M) × (G/N)$ by the second isomorphism theorem, but I'm not sure how to do the above problem. Thanks so much for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint, use arrow-theoretic thinking: $~~A\,\cong$ a subgroup of $B~\iff~ \exists$ injective map $A\to B$.

What map $G\to G/M\times G/N$ do you think you should consider? How does $M\cap N=1$ help?